# automatically multiply two values to give a total jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery question an was wondering if anyone could help me out. 
I have an html table with information in it specifically for stones. I have a price per carat and a price per stone at the end of the table. I wish to have the price per carat multiply by the weight to give the price per stone. I also have a markup box that i have created in which the user inputs a number which is then regarded as a % and is automatically added to the price per carat and price per stone. here is what i have so far:

Here is the jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#markup").keyup(multInputs);

    function multInputs() {
        var $inmult = jQuery(this).val();


        jQuery("tr").each(function () {
            var $val1 = jQuery('.price .amount', this).text().substring(1);

            var $mult = $inmult / 100;
            $mult += 1;
            var $total = $val1 * $mult;



            jQuery('.adjprice .amount', this).text("$" + $total.toFixed(2));



             $val1 = jQuery('.org_ct', this).text();

             $mult = $inmult / 100;
             $mult += 1;
             $total = $val1 * $mult;



            jQuery('.adj_ct', this).text($total.toFixed(2));

        });


    }
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<span class="markup">Adjust Price: <input name="markup" id="markup"> % </span>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter-blackice">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sku#</th>
            <th>Availability</th>
            <th>Cert #</th>
            <th>Shape</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Clarity</th>
            <th>Cut</th>
            <th>[MM]</th>
            <th style="display:none" class="header">US$/ct</th>
            <th class="header">US$/ct</th>
            <!--<th>CDN$/ct</th>-->
            <th style="display:none" class="header">Hidden Orig Price</th>
            <th class="header">US$/St</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>rerew</td>
            <td>erewr</td>
            <td>wrer</td>
            <td>ewrer</td>
            <td>erwer</td>
            <td>ere</td>
            <td>ewr</td>
            <td>ewrew</td>
            <td>wreew</td>



            <td class="org_ct" style="display:none">
                <td class="adj_ct">1234</td>
            </td>



            <td class="price" style="display:none">
                <td class="adjprice">
<span class="amount"></span>

                </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The number is not automatically being multiplied to give me a price per stone. also the markup is not working either I really appreciate the help. THANKS!

Comment: Do you get a console error? I'm asking because you're doing calc on ALL `<tr>` and the first one is the header, also, can you `console.log` the values, are they being collected correctly? Can you create a fiddle

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have created a  fiddle  here http://jsfiddle.net/steamfunk/h0077dts/ i do not get any console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you need. Note that I un-hid some of the columns to make it easier to work with, you'll need to hide them again.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function iDoMathsGood() {
        $('.amount').map(function () {
            // get all of the elements we'll need to manipulate
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();
            var originalTtl = row.find('.price');
            var adjusted = row.find('.adj_ct');

            // get the numbers we'll need and do some math        
            var cts = Number(row.find('.weight').html());
            var origPPCT = Number(row.find('.org_ct').html()) * 1000;
            var markupPrct = Number($('#markup').val()) / 100;
            var markedupCost = (origPPCT * markupPrct) + origPPCT;

            // do a little more math them set the results
            adjusted.html((markedupCost / 1000).toFixed(2));
            originalTtl.html(((origPPCT * cts) / 1000).toFixed(2));
            return $(this).html(((markedupCost * cts) / 1000).toFixed(2));
        });
    }
    iDoMathsGood();
    $('#markup').keyup(function(){
        iDoMathsGood();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="markup">Adjust Price: <input name="markup" id="markup" value="10"/> % </span>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter-blackice" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sku#</th>
            <th>Availability</th>
            <th>Cert #</th>
            <th>Shape</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Clarity</th>
            <th>Cut</th>
            <th>[MM]</th>
            <th class="header">US$/ct</th>
            <th class="header">US$/ct</th>
            <th class="header">Hidden Orig Price</th>
            <th class="header">US$/St</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>rerew</td>
            <td>erewr</td>
            <td>ewrer</td>
            <td>erwer</td>
            <td class="weight">12</td>
            <td>ewr</td>
            <td>ewr</td>
            <td>ewrew</td>
            <td>wreew</td>
            <td class="org_ct">42.50</td>
            <td class="adj_ct"></td>
            <td class="price"></td>
            <td class="adjprice"> <span class="amount"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>rerew</td>
            <td>erewr</td>
            <td>ewrer</td>
            <td>erwer</td>
            <td class="weight">6</td>
            <td>ewr</td>
            <td>ewr</td>
            <td>ewrew</td>
            <td>wreew</td>
            <td class="org_ct">32.75</td>
            <td class="adj_ct"></td>
            <td class="price"></td>
            <td class="adjprice"> <span class="amount"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you're calling the multInputs function improperly. Don't forget the () when calling a function (or other method).

```
jQuery("#markup").keyup(multInputs);
```

should be

```
jQuery("#markup").keyup(multInputs());
```

From there, you've got a few other errors (to begin with):

- var $inmult = $(this).val();, you're calling this from within the function but without actually having a "this" to be referred to. If you move this within the "each" function, then you'll have a "this" to refer to.
- Of course, make sure you've linked to JQuery! :)
- I would also add a class to the weight  to make it easy to refer to
- I'm not going to debug the whole thing but this should give you a start

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {

   $("#markup").keyup(multInputs());

  function multInputs() {

      $("tr").each(function () {
             var $inmult = $(this).find('td.weight' ).text();

             var $val1 = $('.price .amount', this).text().substring(1);

             var $mult = $inmult / 100;
             $mult += 1;
             var $total = $val1 * $mult;

             $('.adjprice .amount', this).text("$" + $total.toFixed(2));

             $val1 = $('.org_ct', this).text();

             $mult = $inmult / 100;
             $mult += 1;
             $total = $val1 * $mult;

             $('.adj_ct', this).text($total.toFixed(2));

         });
     }
   });
  ```

Comment: I'm not able to test at the moment, I'm on mobile, but I think you'll find that `jQuery("#markup").keyup(multInputs());` binds whatever is *returned* from the `multInputs()` function as the `keyup` event-handler, not the `multInputs()` function itself.